# How to replace IotCoreDefaultApp startup permanently. It returns as headed-startup after reboot (sometimes)

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

Using the newest Windows-10 Iot-Core on a RaspberryPi, I can replace the (single) headed startup/default App via PowerShell command "IotStartup add headed" or I can use the AppXManager to achieve the same. Then I reboot, and the new default/startup headed app appears in the AppXManager as it should.

Sometime later, my Watchdog headless process (background task) then decides to reboot (using ShutdownManager.BeginShutdown(ShutdownKind.Restart, new TimeSpan(0));). After the reboot, the DEFAULT/ORIGINAL IotCoreDefaultApp is sometimes (but not always!) returned to its status as startup app and the headed startup app that I explicitly setup is not started.

**How can I assure that IoT-Core does not replace my headed-startup app with the default one upon reboot?** I'd prefer not to delete the IoTCoreDefaultApp permanently at this stage in development.

Comment: This frustrating BUG (it can't be a feature!) is confirmed here. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=105&t=125739&p=842599#p842599

Comment: Are you still encountering this issue, or is this resolved?  I have not encountered this recently.

Comment: Less frequently in testing (but still a severe iot-core weakness) since I noticed that it has something to do with the scripts behind the AppExplorer Web. Before I close it, I always reset the default headed app. However, it cannot have evaporated since I still have the same iot-core release. We'll see soon in the new one. I am disappointed that no one from Microsoft chimed in anywhere to clear things up.

Comment: I have my application successfully set as DefaultApp on RPI 2. Later I needed to run the same app with wi-fi connection, so I've deployed it to RPI 3 device. And faced the same problem - after reboot, the application is not default anymore. I just tried everything possible, including command line, PowerShell, attempts to write some watchdog application, nothing helped. So today, as last desperate try, I just bought another RPI 3 board and another SD card. And, tadaa, it works perfectly. I'll elaborate more with new SD + old RPI etc. and share my findings.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work now in the newest update-release of iot-core. One can either use the Device-Portal or the "iotstartup" command in powershell. Also, if required, the scripts that handle the default AppStartup are now in C:/AppInstall.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the IoT Core Dashboard App to connect to your device. And then use the admin page to select the startup App. HTH